# The type or namespace name 'GetName' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, console-application

The following code runs in a simple demo but it doesn't compile in my real project.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string AgentName = "Test";
            string SERVICE_NAME = "Agent";
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(AgentName);
            ServiceControllerStatus status = sc.Status;
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Service {0} {1}", SERVICE_NAME, 
                // compile error this next line: 
                Enum.GetName(typeof(ServiceControllerStatus), sc.Status))); 
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> The type or namespace name 'GetName' does not exist in the namespace
>   'UtilLibrary.Enum'

If I change the top namespace in the file (in real project) from `UtilLibrary`to something else like `UtilityLibrary`, it compiles fine. It seems like there would be a conflict with `GetName()` but there is not, nothing comes up in search.

So how can I stay in the same namespace and fix the compile error?

p.s I am new to c#. Also if add dot to change the namespace like `UtilLibrary.General`, that still doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Try fully resolving the namespace of `System.Enum`: `System.Enum.GetName(typeof(ServiceControllerStatus), sc.Status)`. If somebody has done something weird enough to break that, go to `global::System.Enum(...`. That ought to settle its hash.

Comment: `System.Enum.GetName()` did fix the error! So this means there is a name clash? Not sure why it doesn't come up in search.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It was type, clash (not class). I updated the comment.

Comment: Pick good names for namespaces, you'd prefer to avoid names that are already used by keywords and common .NET classes.  Like "Enum".  Find good advice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces).

Comment: As Hans suggests, *if* the library is within your control, `Enum` is a bad idea for a class name, regardless of namespace. Before extension methods, you could say `UtilLibrary.Enum` or whatever, but now it's sketchier. `EnumExt` is one naming convention people use for stuff like that.

Comment: @zar I can't reproduce exactly the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not best practice, you can always specify an alias to solve naming issues

```
using SysEnum = System.Enum;
using LibEnum = Some.Custom.Library.Enum;

//Usage
SysEnum.GetName(typeof(ServiceControllerStatus), sc.Status)));
LibEnum.WhateverMethodIsImplementedHere();
```

Remember that it is usally better to fix the naming, as long as it is your code.